# haw i can add a new text style for my app in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[enter image description here][1]i need to no haw i can add a new text style to my app in android studio ,i was try that one but it does not work

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksfaR.png

Comment: `it does not work` doesn't tell much about what's wrong, can you please be more specific? Does the app crash? If yes - what does the exception stack trace look like?

Answer (score 0):

In your app theme:

```
<item name="fontFamily">@font/ut</item>
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ut</item>
```

where `ut.ttf` is in a `font` folder in your `res` folder.

You can set fonts in code, but it's complicated and there are other styling considerations, stuff you'd need to override on various components etc. Sticking it on the theme kinda takes care of all that app-wide (well, for changing the *typeface* anyway - if you want to change properties like sizes that gets a little more complicated!)

[This](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/whats-your-text-s-appearance-f3a1729192d) is a good general resource on text styling from an Android team member (and explains why the theme takes precedence when it comes to styling)